# Concealing the "Local Properties" of the Constructor Function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-chain

We know that the properties are defined in the Constructor function of an object in Javascript, but on instantiation i personally do not want the object to list the internal properties(in other words, i only want the property defined in the Constructors prototype object to be in the list with the appropriate values)in Browser console.

```
function Person(name,age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.heading=function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
Person.prototype.details=function(){
    console.log('hi'+this.name+' your age is '+this.age);
}
function Student(name,subject){
    Person.call(this,name,26);
    this.subject=subject;
}
Student.prototype=Object.create(Person.prototype);
var student1=new Student('Brian','cs');
```

The properties defined in the Constructors Prototype object should be in the list. Not the internal defined properties.

Comment: Why? Why should that be useful?

Comment: @JonasWilms i want that, my object instance should only inherit the prototype object. So that user can only access the prototype object which has **details** method, which contains every details of the user(name, age etc) in one place.